# Hierarchical data in array list how to sort it based in hierarchy

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list which contains `id` in the following order:-

```
101 -> 103 -> 104 -> 105 -> 106 -> 107
```

Below is the table structure for this :-

```
Parent | Child
null      101
101       103
101       104
103       105
103       106
104       107
```

Now i want to see the data as 
`101 -> 103 -> 105-> 106 -> 104 -> 107`, i.e. in proper hierarchical structure. i.e. first parent then its child and then grandchildren of that child, and then the second child of the parent. There is no restriction on the level of the hierarchy.

What is the most optimum way of doing this in Java?

Comment: Smells like `HashMap` or `LinkedList`...

Comment: I am trying using linkedhashmap but the solution seems to be very expensive.

Comment: your question is not clear. in your example, no parent has more than one children, then what does this mean - `first parent then its child and then grandchildren of that child, and then the second child of the parent`?? update your post with exact input and output for your problem.

Comment: OK....Currently the order that i have in my arraylist is ->
parent->immediate_child_1->immediate_child_2->children(immediate_child_1) -> children(immediate_child_2) 
Now i want the o/p as :-

parent -> immediate_child_1->children(immediate_child_1) -> immediate_child_2 -> children(immediate_child_2).....i guess it clears the air

Comment: Looks like DFS?

Comment: You are doing Depth first search till you stop seeing any child.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

I created a `Node` object with a parent-child relationship.

Then I use DFS to traverse through the `Node`s.

Here is a complete working example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListHierarchy {

    static class Node{
        private Node parent;
        private int value;
        private List<Node> children;

        public Node(int value, Node parent){
            this.value = value;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.children = new ArrayList<>();
            if(parent!=null && parent.children.contains(this)==false) {
                parent.children.add(this);
            }
        }

        public int value() {
            return value;
        }

        public Node parent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public List<Node> children() {
            return children;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(!(obj instanceof Node)){
                return false;
            }
            Node that = (Node) obj;
            return this.value == that.value && this.parent == that.parent;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         *Parent    Child
         * null      101
         * 101       103
         * 101       104
         * 103       105
         * 103       106
         * 104       107
         */

        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        Node n = new Node(101, null); // null parent means root node
        Node n1 = new Node(103, n);
        Node n2 = new Node(104, n);
        Node n3 = new Node(105, n1);
        Node n4 = new Node(106, n1);
        Node n5 = new Node(107, n2);

        nodes.add(n);
        nodes.add(n1);
        nodes.add(n2);
        nodes.add(n3);
        nodes.add(n4);
        nodes.add(n5);

        List<Node> ordered = new ArrayList<>();
        walk(n, ordered);

        System.out.println(ordered);
    }

    /**
     * Using DFS to walk through the Nodes
     * @param root - Root node from which to start DFS.
     * @param ordered - New Empty List to add nodes to.
     */
    public static void walk(Node root, List<Node> ordered) {
        ordered.add(root);
        for(Node child: root.children()) {
            walk(child, ordered);
        }
    }

}
```

> And here is the sample output:

```
[101, 103, 105, 106, 104, 107]
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: yup,works fine..and is more effiient than what i coded,thanks :)

Comment: you are doing their homework for them, are you going to do all their work for them as well when they get  job?